# Laravel, group protected routes usigng sanctum authentication

Tags: laravel-sanctum

How can I group protected routes that use laravel sanctum authentication? I got error message: "Auth guard [:sanctum] is not defined."

I try this code :

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth::sanctum']], function(){

    // send reset password code
    Route::post('/send-password-code', [ResetPasswordController::class, 'sendResetPasswordCode']);

    // reinitialize password
    Route::post('/reset-password', [ResetPasswordController::class, 'reset']);
});
```